# Maven: How to fail maven build when the project found to have a specific version of a dependency?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I have a module which is used as a maven dependency in many springboot projects. We keep on releasing new versions of the module.

Now, it is found that some of the springboot projects uses very old version of the module as dependency. We want to fail the maven build for such project which uses older than a specific version of the module as maven dependency.

Can you please share some pointers to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably use something like the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) to achive that.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum . This is helpful. I tried this, it worked for me. The only issue is that we need to ask all the springboot applications to include this plugin. Is there any way to externalize this? I mean without asking applications to include this plugin in their pom.xml, can we just check the versions in their pom.xml for a specific dependency and fail it if not having the required version?